# How to set the input shape for a chatbot NN

Tags: keras, neural-network, chatbot

I've been trying to make a simple chatbot in python but am having problems with the input shape
my NN is as follows :

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(8,activation='relu', input_shape=(46,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(8,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(len(output[0]), activation = 'softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training,output,epochs = 200, batch_size=8)
```

The input shape of my data is (26, 46) in the form of a bag of words
When I try to chat with the model this error shows

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_141_input to have shape (46,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

and my method of chatting being

```
def chat():
    print("Chat with the bot type quit to end ")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']

        print(random.choice(responses))
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in the predict method I had to use [[]] and since I didn't the error showed up so the fixed code of the chat method would look like this

```
def chat():
    print("Chat with the bot type quit to end ")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        results = model.predict([[bag_of_words(inp, words)]])
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']

        print(random.choice(responses))
```

hope this helps anyone that comes across similar problems